# email captured image through sendgrid

Tags: swift, image, email, sendgrid

So I am trying to send a captured image as an attached file for email using SendGrid. I've defined sendmail function and attachImage method for Email.

```
public extension SendGrid {
    public class Email {
    ......
        public var images: [UIImage]!

        public func attachImage(image: UIImage) {
            if self.images == nil {
                self.images = []
            }
            self.images.append(image)
        }
    }
}
```

then calling this function

```
var sg = SendGrid(username: "*****", password: "*****")
var email = SendGrid.Email()

func sendMail(){
    screenShot()

    do {
        try
        email.addTo("sean@gmail.com", name: "Sehwan")
        email.setFrom("test@test.com", name: "test")
        email.setSubject("Hello Images")
        email.setHtmlBody("<p>Up Thai, Wolfgang, Benihana, Wa.</p><br><br><p>Nice it works</p>")
        email.attachImage(shareImage)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    if(shareImage != nil){
        do {
            try
            sg.send(email, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
                if let json = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    print(json)
                }
            })
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func screenShot(){
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(backgroundImage.frame.size.width, backgroundImage.frame.size.width), false, 0)
    self.view?.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRectMake(0, -40, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
    shareImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Everything works well - screenshot function captures the part of screen so I can share it or save to the phone. Also email part works except that email comes without image file.

Not really sure how I can email captured image in the app as an attachment using sendGrid. I would greatly appreciate any advices.

Answer (score 0):

Their [API reference](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html#-send) describes exactly how to do this.

Pertinent section:

> files   Must be less than 7MB   Files to be attached.
>
> The file contents must be part of the multipart HTTP POST.
>
> Ex: files[file1.jpg]=file1.jpg&files[file2.pdf]=file2.pdf

Comment: their examples are for the files that already have a name and path. When I print captured image i get "<UIImage: 0x7fb760e0af80> size {375, 375} orientation 0 scale 2.000000". Is there a way to give a path to the captured image file in the app?

Comment: btw, thank you so much for editing! I forgot to remove id and password from the code. Again, Thanks